# Showing that we can represent a finite union of intervals as a finite union of pairwise disjoint intervals

Tags: general-topology

Let $K$ be a family of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $A \in K$ iff $A$ can be represented as a finite union of intervals of the form $[x,y)$. Show that $\forall A \in K$ can be represented as a finite union of pairwise disjoint intervals. Show that the canonical representation of a set $A \in K$ is unique.

Ill try to explain my attempt through example. Suppose I have $[1,2) \cup [2,7) \cup [4,9) \cup [12,14)$. Then its clear that I could just as well rewritten this as $[1,9) \cup [12,14)$ and these intervals are disjoint. So I think I get the idea but I am unsure how to show it or prove it in general. As far as showing its unique I do not have any ideas for that.

Comment: Uniqueness doesn't hold unless you impose the condition that the intervals have no endpoints in common. For example, $[0,1) \cup [1, 2) = [0,2)$. In this case, if you know about topology, uniqueness will follow if you can prove that the intervals are the connected components of the set. Alternatively, an interval appears in the decomposition if and only if there is some $x$ in the set $A$ such that it is the largest interval containing $x$ and contained in $A$. For existence, it should be relatively straightforward by induction.

Comment: The induction step will consist of taking the union of one interval of the required form with a finite number of disjoint ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a procedure by which you can make all intervals disjoint:

Suppose you have two intervals in your set $[x_1,y_1)$ and $[x_2,y_2)$ which are not disjoint. Then replace them with their union.

This is clearly an interval of the desired form if either interval is contained in the other. Otherwise, without loss of generality $x_1<x_2$ ($x_1\neq x_2$ because otherwise one interval is contained in the other). Since $[x_2,y_2)$ is not contained in $[x_1,y_1)$, then $y_2>y_1$, and so $[x_1,y_1)\cup[x_2,y_2)=[x_1,y_2)$.

This process must eventually stop, because there are finitely many intervals, and you decrease the number of intervals in your collection at each step. Therefore, you must eventually reach a point where all intervals in the collection are disjoint.

Note however that an expression of this form is not unique, we actually require the **closures** $[x,y]$ to be disjoint for this to be the case. For example

$$[1,12)=[1,6)\cup[6,12)=[1,2)\cup[2,3)\cup\cdots\cup[11,12)$$

are all valid decompositions, however only the first has the property that all closures of the intervals are disjoint: $[1,6]\cap[6,12]=\{6\}$.

The algorithm I described can also be shown to work if we instead require at each step for the closures $[x_1,y_1]$, $[x_2,y_2]$ of the intervals $[x_1,y_1)$, $[x_2,y_2)$ to not be disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{K_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be an enumeration of $K$.

Then let
$K'_1=K_1$, $K'_2=K_2\setminus K_1$, $K'_3=K_3\setminus (K_1\cup K_2)$, etc...

Then $\{K'_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a finite collection of pairwise disjoint intervals.

Comment: $K$ need not be finite. I suspect that you want to let $A\in K$ be the union of the left-closed, right-open intervals $A_1,\ldots,A_n$, let $A_1'=A_1$, $A_2'=A_2\setminus A_1$, etc. As Dave pointed out in the comments, this won’t necessarily give you the canonical representation.